# Подключение sqlite в PHP 5.4.0

Tags: sqlite, php

Доброго дня!

Возникли проблемы при подключении расширения `sqlite` в PHP 5.4.0. В php.ini раскомментированы строки:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_sqlite.dll
```

именно в таком порядке, `phpinfo()` выдает, что всё в порядке, но при попытке обратиться к функции `sqlite_open` - выдает ошибку `Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlite_open()`.
Насколько я помню, в предыдущих версиях нужно было включать три `ext`:

```
 extension=php_pdo.dll
 extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
 extension=php_sqlite.dll
```

Теперь `pdo` поддерживается на уровне ядра. Что я делаю не так?

`sqlite 3.7.7.1, php 5.4.0, apache 2.2.22`.

Comment: Вообщем, смысл в том, что начиная с версии PHP 5.4 поддержка sqlite вынесена в pecl.

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понимаю,  для соединение с базой `SQLite` выше 3 версии необходимо использовать только библиотеку  `PDO`, а вы используете обычную библиотеку.

Объясню по другому - вы пытаетесь с помощью sqlite_open()  соединится с базой SQLite версией  3.7.7.1 - что у вас никогда не получится, так как это только для версий ниже 3.
Для вашей версии вроде как идет функция sqlite3_open  [смотрим тут](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.sqlite3.php) . Но мой вам совет используем либо объектный подход [смотрим тут](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.version.php) или используем драйвер PDO.
Также посмотрте что выводит php_info() касаемо раздела SQLite

Answer (score 0):

SQLITE поддерживается в PHP 5.x.x без всякой возни в конфиге PHP.INI! Все должно работать в данной версии PHP "штатно", так как SQLITE - это не СУБД, а лишь драйвер, расширяющий возможности СУБД MySQL! Точно так же обстоит дело и с MySQLi! У вас все должно было работать в штатной сборке PHP 5.

Comment: SQLIte это СУБД встроенная в PHP - моно сказать так)

Comment: Прошу пояснить фразу: "SQLITE - это не СУБД, а лишь драйвер, расширяющий возможности СУБД MySQL!". Профессор, я не согласен)

Comment: @morin, почитайте здесь: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite#.D0.94.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.B9.D0.BD

Comment: @Dexter, не вижу связи между движком SQLite и СУБД MySQL.